# php array not working

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

This is my first foray into customizing the WP comment form, and it's giving me a bit of trouble.
Ideally, I'd like to have a comment form with 3 fields: Name, Location, and Comment. 
To facilitate that, I'm using arrays:

```
<?php comment_form(array(
    'title_reply'=> 'Please feel free to share your home owning hopes and dreams.',
    'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', $fields ),
    'label_submit' => 'Share',
    )); 
    ?>
```

In the comment list, I want the comment to display and just below that have "Name | Location"

```
<div class="comment-content"><?php comment_text(); ?><?php comment_author(); ?> | <?php echo $comment_author_url ?> </div>
```

As you can see on the [live site](http://zoparealty.com/share/), it isn't quite coming out that way. Any ideas why that may be? Tips and insight are appreciated.

functions.php

```
<?php 

if ( ! function_exists( 'twentyeleven_comment' ) ) :
/**
 * Template for comments and pingbacks.
 *
 * To override this walker in a child theme without modifying the comments template
 * simply create your own twentyeleven_comment(), and that function will be used instead.
 *
 * Used as a callback by wp_list_comments() for displaying the comments.
 *
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 */
function twentyeleven_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    switch ( $comment->comment_type ) :
        case 'pingback' :
        case 'trackback' :
    ?>
    <li class="post pingback">
        <p><?php _e( 'Pingback:', 'twentyeleven' ); ?> <?php comment_author_link(); ?><?php edit_comment_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?></p>
    <?php
            break;
        default :
    ?>
    <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <article id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" class="comment">

            <div class="comment-content"><?php comment_text(); ?><?php comment_author(); ?> | <?php echo $comment_author_url ?> </div>

        </article><!-- #comment-## -->

    <?php
            break;
    endswitch;
}
endif; // ends check for twentyeleven_comment()

// Custom callback to list comments in the your-theme style
function custom_comments($comment, $args, $depth) {
  $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    $GLOBALS['comment_depth'] = $depth;
  ?>
    <li id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" <?php comment_class() ?>>
        <div class="comment-author vcard"><?php commenter_link() ?></div>
        <div class="comment-meta"><?php printf(__('Posted %1$s at %2$s <span class="meta-sep">|</span> <a href="%3$s" title="Permalink to this comment">Permalink</a>', 'your-theme'),
                    get_comment_date(),
                    get_comment_time(),
                    '#comment-' . get_comment_ID() );
                    edit_comment_link(__('Edit', 'your-theme'), ' <span class="meta-sep">|</span> <span class="edit-link">', '</span>'); ?></div>
  <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') _e("\t\t\t\t\t<span class='unapproved'>Your comment is awaiting moderation.</span>\n", 'your-theme') ?>
          <div class="comment-content">
            <?php comment_text() ?>
        </div>
        <?php // echo the comment reply link
            if($args['type'] == 'all' || get_comment_type() == 'comment') :
                comment_reply_link(array_merge($args, array(
                    'reply_text' => __('Reply','your-theme'),
                    'login_text' => __('Log in to reply.','your-theme'),
                    'depth' => $depth,
                    'before' => '<div class="comment-reply-link">',
                    'after' => '</div>'
                )));
            endif;
        ?>
<?php } // end custom_comments

// Custom callback to list pings
function custom_pings($comment, $args, $depth) {
       $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
        ?>
            <li id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" <?php comment_class() ?>>
                <div class="comment-author"><?php printf(__('By %1$s on %2$s at %3$s', 'your-theme'),
                        get_comment_author_link(),
                        get_comment_date(),
                        get_comment_time() );
                        ?></div>
    <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') _e('\t\t\t\t\t<span class="unapproved">Your trackback is awaiting moderation.</span>\n', 'your-theme') ?>
            <div class="comment-content">
                <?php comment_text() ?>
            </div>
<?php } // end custom_pings

// Produces an avatar image with the hCard-compliant photo class
function commenter_link() {
    $commenter = get_comment_author_link();
    if ( ereg( '<a[^>]* class=[^>]+>', $commenter ) ) {
        $commenter = ereg_replace( '(<a[^>]* class=[\'"]?)', '\\1url ' , $commenter );
    } else {
        $commenter = ereg_replace( '(<a )/', '\\1class="url "' , $commenter );
    }
    $avatar_email = get_comment_author_email();
    $avatar = str_replace( "class='avatar", "class='photo avatar", get_avatar( $avatar_email, 80 ) );
    echo $avatar . ' <span class="fn n">' . $commenter . '</span>';
} // end commenter_link

if (!function_exists('iweb_reverse_comments')) {
    function iweb_reverse_comments($comments) {
        return array_reverse($comments);
    }
}
add_filter ('comments_array', 'iweb_reverse_comments');

// custom comment field
function my_fields($fields) {
$fields['Location'] = '';
return $fields;
}
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','my_fields');

?>
```

share.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Share
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="content-left">

    <?php comments_template(); ?> 

</div><!-- end content-left -->
<div class="content-right">

    <?php wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'twentyeleven_comment' )); ?></ul>

</div><!-- end content-right -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't think it's twentyeleven_comment that you have to edit.
try an echo in the twentyeleven_comment to see if it's the right function.

```
echo "twentyeleven_comment ";
exit;
```

i think twentyeleven_comment show all comments of a post in the post view not the post list.

Comment: I'm sorry, as I mentioned I'm still very new to this. I searched through http://www.php.net/ and didn't find much direction on how to echo.exit. Can you provide an example? Thank you.

Comment: i was triying to help you not to mock you, anyways good luck.

Comment: Yes, I know you were trying to help! And thank you. I was simply seeing if you might be able to explain a bit more in depth.